# GORM one to many : filter one with given many

Tags: grails, grails-orm

[In this link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany)

The one to many relation is :

```
    class Author {
           static hasMany = [books: Book]
           String name 
     }
```

If we are **not** specifying belongsTo in Book, i.e

```
class Book {
    String title
}
```

How to filter authors with given books.

```
def books=[book1,book2,book3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer HQL.

```
Author.executeQuery("select a from Author a join a.books as b where b in (:bookList)", [booklist: books])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [create criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) to get the authors:

```
    def bookList = //some book list
    def authors = Author.createCriteria().list {
        books {
            'in'('title', bookList*.title)
        }
    }*.name
    println "Authors = ${authors}"
```